# Cant pass a variable from Controller to the View , Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a controller like this:

```
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->myvar = "Hello";
    }
}
```

and index.phtml view part:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body
<h1><?php echo $this->myvar; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason I am not able to see Hello word on view.. and the Error is this i get:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\myZend\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php on line 19

I can see that something with assinging the variable in controller is the problem but i dont why, is this the correct way to assign a value into a variable... Am I missing something else??

ThNKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way in zf2 to set variable and pass to the view:

```
           return new ViewModel(array(
           'varName' => $value,
         ));
```

Then retrieve it in your view:

```
          echo $this->varName;
```

Comment: ok great it works, how do I also define where to go? which file , why in this case it goes to index.phtml, for ex if i have to go somewhere else where do i need to add the name of the phtml name

Comment: @Lulzim per default it is usually `module-name/controller-name/action.phtml`, in case for some reason you want to change the default, you can do this inside your controllers action via `$vm = new ViewModel(); $vm->setTemplate('module/controller/different.phtml'); return $vm->setVariables(array( /**vars...*/))`

Comment: I also have another issue, for ex i can acces the page like this: myZend.localhost which is fine it opens by default indexAction, how come if i add a new method within that controller, or for ex why myZend.localhost/index does return me 404 error, when it is supposed to call indexAction method?

What i want specifically is, i wanna create a new method and add some new var on it and pass to another view...

Comment: its the same as it has by default Zend.. I havent changed anything... So u saying that i have to declare all the actions and controllers on that file??

Comment: if you take a look at the module.config.php, you have to set new controller in the section :

'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\New' => 'Application\Controller\NewController'
        ),
    ),
If you won't do this, you can get 404 error. Sam please correct me if I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $view = new ViewModel ();
   $view->myvar = "Hello";
   return $view;
}
```